# Clojure: Remove item from sorted-set-by

Tags: data-structures, clojure, set

How can I remove an element from a sorted-set-by? My problem is as follows:

```
;; Set works fine
(-> #{:a :b :c :d}
    (disj :c))
=> #{:b :d :a}

;; Sorted set works fine
(-> (sorted-set :a :b :c :d)
    (disj :c))
 => #{:a :b :d}

;; Set sorted by custom function does not work
(let [values {:a {:x 1}
              :b {:x 0.4}
              :c {:x 9}
              :d {:x 5}}
      x-val (fn [a b]
              (if (> (get-in values [a :x]) (get-in values [b :x]))
                1
                -1))]
  (-> (sorted-set-by x-val :a :b :c :d) 
      (disj :c)))
  => #{:b :a :d :c} ;; should be #{:b :a :d}
```

Results won't change if I modify the `x-val` function to

```
x-val (fn [a b]
        (cond 
          (identical? a b) 0
          (> (get-in values [a :x]) (get-in values [b :x])) 1
          :else -1))]
```

- Why does this not work?
- How can I make this work?

**Bonus question**
I want to try a heavily modified version of this to speed up a working A* implementation. Are there better datastructures to keep a set sorted by a map item?

Comment: the second version of x-val does work for me - although I would just use `compare` on the :x value for more reliability.

Comment: See the [elaborated example on clojuredocs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-set-by) -- the effect you're seeing is likely to be related to their issue of not being able to find an element. I don't know enough about the innards of `sorted-set-by` to say what's causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparator function for `sorted-set-by` should return a boolean rather than an integer.

Replace

```
(fn [a b]
  (if (> (get-in values [a :x]) (get-in values [b :x]))
    1
    -1))
```

with

```
(fn [a b]
  (> (get-in values [a :x]) (get-in values [b :x])))
```

and it should work correctly.

**EDIT:** To clarify, you can use compare-style functions instead of boolean functions for the comparator, but in that case that function will also be used for equality tests on the set. If you don't want to specify equality explicitly and rather would like Clojure to use a default, use boolean.

If you do recognize the equality case and return 0 for it, as in your 2nd example, the `disj` does work as intended. It is not correct that the results won't change.

Comment: Multiple sources like [Comparators in Clojure](https://github.com/jafingerhut/thalia/blob/master/doc/other-topics/comparators.md#user-content-boolean-comparators) and *Clojure Programming* (p.107) disagree - i.e. predicates are turned into comparators with  `(if (pred a b) -1 (if (pred b a) 1 0))` - i.e. equality is declared when the predicate is false regardless of the order of the arguments.

Comment: @PeerReynders I don't see how that disagrees with what I wrote - though admittedly I may have expressed myself not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - as mentioned above, for some reason restarting the REPL made my ```(comp ...)``` code work.

Comment: @Rörd - your explanation with reference to equality detection via predicates is unclear to the point of being misleading. At first it seems to almost start out at "predicates won't detect equality" to then end up at "Clojure's [magic] default [mechanism] for equality" (because predicates don't detect equality???). Predicates **can** detect equality *if they are designed to do so* - for example `>` detects equality by virtue of a value never being greater than itself.

Comment: The problem in the initial code sample has nothing to do with whether a predicate (which returns a boolean) or comparator (which returns an integer) is used as the comparison function. @waechtertroll's first code was inadequate because **it never detected equality which is necessary to facilitate member removal** - the second version addressed that shortcoming.

Comment: From your description it isn't clear whether you actually understood why your predicate version "worked" - because in this context your predicate function is *converted into a comparator* by using `(if (pfn a b) 1 (if (pfn b a) -1 0))` - which does detect equality (provided `pfn` will return `false` to both `(pfn a b)` and `(pfn b a)` for `(= a b)` - which in this case it does).

Comment: In this context I see the option of using a predicate as a comparison function as a mere convenience to reuse already existing predicates. Personally I would always choose a comparator over a predicate when I have to design a custom comparison function - to me, explicit return of `-1`, `0`, `1` (and/or) use of [`compare`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/compare) is much easier "to reason about" than dealing with `false`, `true` through the predicate-to-comparator conversion.

Comment: Above `(if (pfn a b) 1 (if (pfn b a) -1 0))` should have been `(if (pfn a b) -1 (if (pfn b a) 1 0))`.

Comment: @PeerReynders That conversion wouldn't be able to detect equality with a `<=` kind of predicate, though. In that case it would need to be `(if (pfn a b) (if (pfn b a) 0 -1) 1)`, or `(if (pfn a b) (if (pfn b a) 0 -1) (if (pfn b a) 1 0))` which would work universally.

Comment: What matters is what Clojure actually does to use your predicate as a comparator - have a look at the addendum to my post. As it is your proposed solution will generate an output of `#{:d :a :b}`, the **reverse** of the desired output - which could further emphasize that using predicates for comparison isn't as straightforward as it may initially seem.

Comment: @PeerReynders I can see how my phrasing "use a default" would be misleading, "generate the right thing" would probably be better. My point was though that if you use a predicate, Clojure will take care of details for you so there's less potential for doing something wrong (like forgetting to specify the equality case as OP did).

Comment: @PeerReynders And the fact I got the order wrong in my answer actually supports my claim that predicate functions are preferable, too: I only got it wrong because OP was returning 1 first and -1 second, that's the kind of confusing detail that predicates avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You were already there

```
(let [values {:a {:x 1}
              :b {:x 0.4}
              :c {:x 9}
              :d {:x 5}}
      x-val (fn [a b]
              (let [{x :x} (values a)
                    {y :x} (values b)]
                (if (not= a b) 
                  (compare x y)
                  0)))] 
  (-> (sorted-set-by x-val :a :b :c :d) 
      (disj :c)))
```

The key being that equality (returning a comparson value of 0) is needed to support removal. Even

```
(let [values {:a {:x 1}
              :b {:x 0.4}
              :c {:x 9}
              :d {:x 5}}
      x-val (fn [a b]
              (let [{x :x} (values a)
                    {y :x} (values b)]
                  (compare x y)))]
  (-> (sorted-set-by x-val :a :b :c :d) 
      (disj :c)))
```

will work. Your version with [`identical?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/identical_q) works in my REPL (on [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/)) - so there must be something else going on. If you try

```
(let [values {:a {:x 1}
              :b {:x 0.4}
              :c {:x 9}
              :d {:x 5}}
      x-val (fn [a b]
              (cond 
                (identical? a b) 0
                  (> (get-in values [a :x]) (get-in values [b :x])) 1
                    :else -1))]
  (-> (sorted-set-by x-val :a :b :c :d) 
      (disj :c)))
```

on [Try Clojure](http://www.tryclj.com/) you can see for yourself.
Of course your initial version could be modified as follows

```
(let [values {:a {:x 1}
              :b {:x 0.4}
              :c {:x 9}
              :d {:x 5}}
      x-val (fn [a b]
              (if (= a b)
                0
                (if (> (get-in values [a :x]) (get-in values [b :x])) 1 -1)))]
  (-> (sorted-set-by x-val :a :b :c :d) 
      (disj :c)))
```

### Addendum: How does Clojure get (potentially) three states out of a two argument predicate?

A brief REPL session should illustrate what Clojure does to use predicates as comparators:

```
user=> (> 1 2)
false
user=> (> 2 1)
true
user=> (> 1 1)
false
user=> (def cmp-from-gt (comparator >))
#'user/cmp-from-gt
user=> (cmp-from-gt 1 2)
1
user=> (cmp-from-gt 2 1)
-1
user=> (cmp-from-gt 1 1)
0
user=> (defn pfn->cfn 
  #_=>   [pfn]
  #_=>   (fn [a b] 
  #_=>     (if (pfn a b) -1 (if (pfn b a) 1 0))))
#'user/pfn->cfn
user=> (def cfn-from-gt (pfn->cfn >))
#'user/cfn-from-gt
user=> (cfn-from-gt 1 2)
1
user=> (cfn-from-gt 2 1)
-1
user=> (cfn-from-gt 1 1)
0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... restarting with a clean REPL showed that my second version indeed does work. I can't imagine why restarting the REPL had any effect, as I'm evaluating the complete code from an emacs buffer (Arch linux here, too), but I had that behaviour before. I chose Rörd's answer for being most concise, together with Peer Reynders' explanation.